# Is it a good practice to pass many error items in an exception?

Tags: c#, exception

Suppose I have a method that looks like this:

```
Dictinary<MyClass, string> myDicItemsWithErrors = new Dictinary<MyClass, string>();

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        foreach (MyClass item in collection)
        {
            try
            {
                item.DoSomething();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                myDicItemsWithErrors.Add(item, ex.Message);
    
                throw;
            }
        }
    
    
    
        throw new MyCustomException(myDicItemsWithErrors);
    }
```

The idea is that who invokes the method, in the UI for example, know which elements present problems and which no, so UI can show information about the error of each item, just it has to search the item in the dictionary and if it is not there, it is correct, if not, the UI can show the message.

But I don't know if this a good practice or there are another way to show which errors occur when I try to process many items at the same time.

Comment: If you `throw;`, your dictionary will only have one item and `MyCustomException` will never be thrown, so whether or not it's a good practice, it's not actually happening **in*** practice.

Comment: It's also not a great idea to catch _all_ exceptions. Specify which exception you expect to get, and catch that one. Catching all exceptions like this makes it hard to debug code.

Comment: ...unless you call this multiple times. Since `myDicItemsWithErrors` is only instantiated once, you could accumulate exception messages from those calls, one per call. You should consider accepting `collection` as a parameter, instantiating the dictionary as a local variable, and returning the dictionary from the method. There's too much *action at a distance* here.

Comment: Catching many exceptions will be slow. I would just catch 1-3 Exceptions then let the user correct his errors.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I personally pass many error items in an exception and even log errors to for easy tracking of issues in my solution
Dictinary<MyClass, string> myDicItemsWithErrors = new Dictinary<MyClass, string>();

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    foreach (MyClass item in collection)
    {
        try
        {
            item.DoSomething();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           _logger.LogInformation($" {item}");
            myDicItemsWithErrors.Add(item, ex.Message);

           throw xe.InnerException;
        }
    }



    throw new MyCustomException(myDicItemsWithErrors);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some examples

Comment: In this case, when you throw the inner exception, doesn't it make to finish the method and  throw only onle exception? I mean, if one exception happens, the code will not arise to MyCustomExcception.